# VAR=${n:-m} usage in Bash

Tags: bash, syntax

I want to write a Genetic Algorithm for bash based in the one posted here: http://father-natures.blogspot.mx/2013/04/implementing-genetic-algorithm-in-bash.html. I am quite inexpert in advance scripting and I don't get what VAR=${n:-m} stands for. My guess was that things like:

```
POOL_SIZE=${1:-6}
```

Make  $1=-6, however when I check $1 it is empty and when I check $POOLSIZE I get 6.

```
libertad@engrane4:~$ echo "POOL_SIZE"
6
```

This is quite confusing for me. If I wanted the variable to be 6 I would write:

```
POOL_SIZE=6
```

Could you tell me what am I missing (what else is this assignation doing)?

Thank you,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sets a default in case `$1` is empty.

From [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion in the Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> **${parameter:-word}**
>
> If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.
>   Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

#### Example

```
$ echo ${a:-"hello"}
hello
$ a="test"
$ echo ${a:-"hello"}
test
```

---

### Based on your comment

> Thanks, @fedorqui. The original variables were POOL_SIZE=${1:-6},
>   REPRO_CHANCE=${2:-30}, BEST_FITS=${3:-70}. Now I am wondering if
>   ${POOL_SIZE:-6}, ${REPRO_CHANCE:-30} and ${BEST_FITS:-70} would be the
>   same and why is the numeration needed

If you have

```
POOL_SIZE=${1:-6}
REPRO_CHANCE=${2:-30}
BEST_FITS=${3:-70}
```

it is because `POOL_SIZE`, `REPRO_CHANCE` and `BEST_FITS` are supposed to contain the value of `$1`, `$2` and `$3`. Any `$n` means the `nth` parameter, for example from a script. So if you have the following script:

```
$ cat a
#!/bin/bash

POOL_SIZE=${1:-6}
REPRO_CHANCE=${2:-30}
BEST_FITS=${3:-70}

echo "POOL_SIZE=$POOL_SIZE"
echo "REPRO_CHANCE=$REPRO_CHANCE"
echo "BEST_FITS=$BEST_FITS"
```

Then its execution with different amount of parameters would yield:

```
$ ./a
POOL_SIZE=6
REPRO_CHANCE=30
BEST_FITS=70

$ ./a 2 2 2
POOL_SIZE=2
REPRO_CHANCE=2
BEST_FITS=2

$ ./a 24 2
POOL_SIZE=24
REPRO_CHANCE=2
BEST_FITS=70
```

I hope it makes it clear.

---

Note also that `${var:-value}` and `${var-value}` are not the same: [What is the difference between ${var:-word} and ${var-word}?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31136720/1983854).

Comment: Thanks, @fedorqui. The original variables were POOL_SIZE=${1:-6}, REPRO_CHANCE=${2:-30}, BEST_FITS=${3:-70}. Now I am wondering if ${POOL_SIZE:-6}, ${REPRO_CHANCE:-30} and ${BEST_FITS:-70} would be the same and why is the numeration needed.

Comment: @LibertadPantoja I just updated the answer so that it gives more information about the parameters. Let me know if it is not clear.