# What is the difference between ${var:-word} and ${var-word}?

Tags: bash, parameters

I found the following command in a bash script:

```
git blame $NOT_WHITESPACE --line-porcelain "${2-@}" -- "$file"
```

What does this `${2-@}` mean? Trying out, it returns the 2nd argument, and "@" if it doesn't exist. [According to the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), `${2:-@}` should do the same. I tried it, and it indeed does the same. What's the difference? Where is it documented? The man page does not seem to say anything about this notation.

Comment: See `man bash`, `Parameter Expansion`. There is no difference beween the two forms but as far as I remember the second one `${2:.@}` should be preferred.

Comment: @helpermethod there is a slight difference. See my answer.

Comment: @fedorqui Thank you for the correction, totally forgot about the difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Bash hackers wiki - parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value):

> ${PARAMETER:-WORD}
>
> ${PARAMETER-WORD}
>
> If the parameter PARAMETER is unset (never was defined) or null
>   (empty), this one expands to WORD, otherwise it expands to the value
>   of PARAMETER, as if it just was ${PARAMETER}. **If you omit the :
>   (colon), like shown in the second form, the default value is only used
>   when the parameter was unset, not when it was empty.**
>
> ```
> echo "Your home directory is: ${HOME:-/home/$USER}."
> echo "${HOME:-/home/$USER} will be used to store your personal data."
> ```
>
> If HOME is unset or empty, everytime you want to print something
>   useful, you need to put that parameter syntax in.
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> read -p "Enter your gender (just press ENTER to not tell us): " GENDER
> echo "Your gender is ${GENDER:-a secret}."
> ```
>
> It will print "Your gender is a secret." when you don't enter the
>   gender. Note that the default value is used on expansion time, it is
>   not assigned to the parameter.