# Adding default to bash script variable

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I have a bash script that uses `$1` to process a command line argument.

I want to modify this script to work even when a command line argument isn't given; in that case I want the script to use a default value.

I don't know how to do this; basically I figure I need to replace `$1` with my own variable and have a line at the start of the program that checks whether a value was passed for `$1`, and if not to use the default that I'll provide. But I don't know the syntax for that. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
var=${1:-default}
```

From the given link:

> **${parameter:-word}**
>
> If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.
>   Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

See an example:

```
$ echo "$v"

$ t=${v:-hello}
$ echo "$t"
hello
$ v=2
$ t=${v:-hello}
$ echo "$t"
2
```

And note also that `${var:-value}` and `${var-value}` are not the same: [What is the difference between ${var:-word} and ${var-word}?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31136720/1983854).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo "${1:-"my default"}"
```

in your script (e. g. `foo.sh`) to see the effect of the `:-` modifier.

Notice that in case you pass an empty string to your script, also the default kicks in:

```
$ ./foo.sh ""
my default
```

So you cannot distinguish the empty string from a not-given argument this way.

In case you need to have that distinction, you should rely on `$#` to tell you the number of arguments:

```
if [ $# = 0 ]
then
  echo "my default"
else
  echo "$1"
fi
```

=>

```
$ printf "[%s]\n" "$(./foo.sh "")"
[]
```

Comment: Actually, I didn't know about `${a-b}` yet and would consider it superior to using `$#`.

Comment: @cdarke so does `[ $# -eq 0 ]`

Comment: @cdarke Absolutely correct.  In these cases I prefer the first as it results in the same, is probably cheaper, is less to type, etc.  But as soon as comparisons like `(( $# > 5 ))` are involved, the numeric syntax is probably nicer to read.

Comment: @User112638726 true, old Bourne shell syntax.  But `=` was used, not `-eq`.

Comment: I always considered `-eq`, `-lt`, etc. a clutch and a second-best solution.  Using `=`, `>=`, etc. help with their visual to prevent errors, so I prefer them if possible.