# What do these parameter expansions mean?

Tags: linux, command

Please explain the linux command:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.sh'"${1:-}"'*' -exec ${2:-file} {} \; ;
```

Specifically I would like to understand the following parts:

- `${1:-}`
- `${2:-file}`

What they actually mean/do? Is there any Linux reference materials I could read to know more on these types of syntax?

Comment: `man file` and http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Comment: `man file` will not help here, and you are better off reading the actual `bash` man page (under Parameter Expansion) than the ABS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VAR=${n:-m} usage in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413107/var-n-m-usage-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

These are bash variable substitutions:

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

They substitute the value followed by the":-" if the variable that precedes the ":-" has not been defined. The $1 and $2 variables refer to the first and second arguments passed to the script or function.